# Centering selectList

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, html, selectlist

[image]I have two selectLists that are wrapped around an outputPanel but I'm not sure how to align them in the center. I know I could do it possibly w/margin but is there a cleaner way to do it?

```
<apex:outputPanel id="panel1" style="align:center;">

  <apex:selectList size="7" value="{!childObjToMig}" id="related_lists">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!children}"/>
  </apex:selectList>

  <apex:commandButton value="=>" action="{!giveChild}" reRender="panel1"/>

  <apex:commandButton value="<=" action="{!returnChild}" reRender="panel1"/>

 <apex:selectList size="7" value="{!childObjToRem}" style="width:115px;" id="migration_list">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!migrateList}"/>
 </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: please show a screen shot; also, since select lists just render as HTML, you could get additional support by posting native HTML on stackoverflow

Comment: @cropredy [so] is probably not appropriate, actually, because we're talking about tweaking HTML elements that we have little control over; this problem is very language specific as written. If it'd been just a plain set of div/span elements, then it would be appropriate there.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by adding the style to the panelGrid, then fixing your outputPanel style.

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="1" style="display: table; width: 100%">
<apex:outputPanel id="panel1" style="text-align: center; display: block">

  <apex:selectList size="7" value="{!childObjToMig}" id="related_lists">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!children}"/>
  </apex:selectList>

  <apex:commandButton value="=>" action="{!giveChild}" reRender="panel1"/>

  <apex:commandButton value="<=" action="{!returnChild}" reRender="panel1"/>

 <apex:selectList size="7" value="{!childObjToRem}" style="width:115px;" id="migration_list">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!migrateList}"/>
 </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Here's a very simple, self-contained example:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:panelGrid columns="1" style="display: table; width: 100%">
            <apex:outputPanel style="text-align: center; display: block;">
                <apex:selectList />
                <apex:commandButton />
                <apex:commandButton />
                <apex:selectList />
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```